# How can I use brackets for serial numbers like 1, 2, 3

Tags: bibliographies, brackets

I want to write the reference numbers like the following in MS WORD. How can I write in such a manner?

> [1] Brattin WJ, Glenda EA. 1 Free Radical Biol Med 1985;1:27.
>
> [2] Osawa T, Kavakishi S, Namiki M. In: Kuroda Y, Shankal DM, Waters
>   MD, editors.
>
> [3] Subramoniam A, Evans DA, Kajasekharan S, Pushpangadan P. Indian J
>   Exp Biol 1998;3h:385.
>
> [4] Lakshmi M, Rajalaksbmi S, Parani M, Anuratha
>   CS, Ajay parida A. Theoretical Appl Genetics

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx.  I have edited your title and text to make the question slightly easier to understand.  Is it intentional that reference [4] is a continuation of reference [3]?  Generally, the LaTeX way to deal with such references is via bibliography styles and `\cite` commands.  The standard `\bibliographystyle{plain}` style produces reference numbers of the form you request.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? Does the OP want to do that in Word? If so, this is the wrong place for this...

Comment: @Vivi I think he wants what he has in Word for LaTeX

Answer (score 6):

I you only have a few references, the simplest way is to use `\cite` commands in the text and a bibliography list at the end of the document as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{Brattin} and some more text \cite{Osawa,Subramoniam}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Brattin} Brattin WJ, Glenda EA. 1 Free Radical Biol Med
  1985;1:27.

\bibitem{Osawa} Osawa T, Kavakishi S, Namiki M. In: Kuroda Y, Shankal
  DM, Waters MD, editors.

\bibitem{Subramoniam} Subramoniam A, Evans DA, Kajasekharan S,
  Pushpangadan P. Indian J Exp Biol 1998;3h:385.

\bibitem{Lakshmi} Lakshmi M, Rajalaksbmi S, Parani M, Anuratha CS,
  Ajay parida A. Theoretical Appl Genetics
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The argument to `\bibitem` is the key you use in the `\cite` command to refer to the given entry.  The `{99}` after `\begin{thebibliography}` ensures that there is enough space left for two digit labels; replace it with `{999}` if you have between 100 and 999 references.

If you have many references, or references you are likely to want to use in another document, then you should put your references in an external file and use either the traditional `bibtex` mechanism or the `biber/biblatex` combination with appropriate choice of bibliogrphy style.  See [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/15925) for starting on `biblatex`.  For `bibtex` see the references in the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html).  Your external bibliography file will have to be structured according to the expectations of these programs.